# VisualStateManager.GoToState returning false

Tags: c#, windows, uwp, windows-10-universal

I created an Universal Windows 10 project, added a TemplateControl, and I'm trying to insert some VisualStates to it, however when I attempt to change the control status using GoToState, I got false as return value and it does not run on my Storyboard.
The following is my code:

```xml
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="control:PaletItem">
            <Grid x:Name="RootElement">
                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                        <VisualState x:Name="Full">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ColorAnimation Duration="0:0:0.1" To="Red" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="MainGrid" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </VisualState>
                        <VisualState x:Name="Empty">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ColorAnimation Duration="0:0:0.1" To="Gray" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="MainGrid" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </VisualState>
                        <VisualState x:Name="Incomplete">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ColorAnimation Duration="0:0:0.1" To="Yellow" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="MainGrid" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </VisualState>
                        <VisualState x:Name="Reserved">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ColorAnimation Duration="0:0:0.1" To="Orange" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="MainGrid" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </VisualState>
                    </VisualStateGroup>
                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

                <Grid Name="MainGrid" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">

                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

Class:

```
[TemplateVisualState(Name = "Empty", GroupName = "CommonStates")]
[TemplateVisualState(Name = "Full", GroupName = "CommonStates")]
[TemplateVisualState(Name = "Incomplete", GroupName = "CommonStates")]
[TemplateVisualState(Name = "Reserved", GroupName = "CommonStates")]
public sealed class PaletItem : Button, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Can someone help me? Pls

Comment: Where are you calling `VisualStateManager.GoToState()`?

Comment: Your visual states work for me. If you want help with this, please do as @DecadeMoon suggested and show how/where you call `VisualStateManager.GoToState()`.